# Replace the values of column in a dataframe according to row number

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 4 columns, and I modified some values of the first column. Now, I want to replace just the modified values in the column.

```
library(tidyverse)

value <- iris[1:20,]
```

let us suppose I extracted rows randomly modified the value in `Sepal.Length`. For example, I modified row number 2,5,8 and 9. Now everything on the data frame is same except the values of `sepal.length` in row 2,5,8,9.

```
changedvalue <- %the value that I changed in row 2,5,8,and 9 of the first column
```

How can I replace row number 2,5,8 and 9 in the original dataframe `value` ?

I tried doing this

```
value[order(as.numeric(rownames(changedvalues))),]
```

I cannot figure out a way to do it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
value[c(2,5,8,9) , ] <- changedvalues[c(2,5,8,9),]
```

Comment: Thank you, but 2,5,8,9 is just an examples. The values are changed randomly and there will be hundreds of rows.

Comment: Then why you not just assign the changedvalues to be the original values like this `value  <- changedvalues ` ?

Comment: Sorry, I could not clarify. The changed dataframe has different amount of rows than original dataframe. A sample is taken from the original and modified, and only the modified values needs to be replaced back into the original dataframe.